# How to integrate unity apk in android studio behind a button?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, apk, unity-container

I have an apk file from unity3d and want to integrate in android studio behind a button. How can I do this ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the unity project as a library.

Check here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary-Android.html